# My card reader doesn't show up at all, but previously did in 10.10

Tags: 10.10, card-reader

I bought a pin-based-USB powered internal media card reader and it worked perfectly when I first installed Ubuntu 10.10 a month ago.  I used it a few times since and today I booted up the computer and it's not working.

Here's how it used to work:

- In `nautilus->computer`, 5 "drives" would display even when no card was inserted.
- One for each slot (SD, XD, CF/MS, etc).
- Opening one w/o a card would initiate a "Please insert card." dialog.
- Inserting a card would automatically open nautilus.

Now:

- No drives display at all whether cards are inserted or not.
- `lsusb` lists the following (which seems to indicate that it's not being detected)

  ```
  Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
  Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc.   (my keyboard/mouse)
  Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
  Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
  Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)  
  Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
  Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
  Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  ```
- (Side note: all of my USB ports are 2.0 + 1 USB port which is 3.0, why does everything say 1.1/2.0?)

I tried using `ubuntu-bug` but for USB devices it expects you to be able to remove and insert them while the computer is running (obviously this is something you probably shouldn't be doing when you're dealing with devices plugged straight into the USB pins).

Comment: Have you tried the card reader on another computer or another OS?

Comment: There's nothing in that lsusb output that looks like a card reader, check your dmesg to see what happened. Also your definition is a little confusing  "pin-based-USB powered internal media card reader". So... is it an external device or not? Got a make and model?

Comment: "2.0 + 1 USB port which is 3.0" WHAT?

Comment: @Hello71 All USB ports are 2.0 except there is one that is 3.0

Comment: @Nayamiou Card reader doesn't have a USB plug, only a USB connector (internal) and I have no other desktops to test it on

Comment: @ppetraki ya I meant an internal media card reader which connects via the internal USB pins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a hardware error, either the device is broken or the connector has come out from inside your computer.

When the device doesn't appear in lsusb then you're in serious trouble because that means the most basic detection has failed and it's rarely a software issue. To double check that it's not a software issue use a liveCD and boot from that, test if it works there.

Comment: If you just bought it few months ago, it's probalby still under warranty, contact the manufacturer to see if it can exchange you a new one or repair it for free.

Comment: I'm going to try and return it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue and could solve it by **rebooting.**
If you can make sure that your **card reader is fine**, then **restarting Ubuntu** should be a fix (**with the card reader inserted**), though not the best fix.

> What I feel is that the hot plug
>   option of card reader is not working
>   with 11.04